# Internet Explorer freezing while using Slickgrid on Windows 2007

Tags: grid, slickgrid

I'm using Slickgrid to display the results on the screen, it is working fine in IE in windows XP, but when I use windows 2007 it is not working properly in Internet Explorer, but it is working properly in Firefox and Chrome.

The problem is when I take the scroll bar to the end of the list the screen hangs up, and I have to restart the Internet explorer, if I won't take the scroll bar to the end of the list it is working fine.

If any solution please post.

Comment: You mean Windows Seven, right?